# Webservices JSON where to start?

Tags: c#, json, web-services

I have a webpage where users can fill in data, this data is inserted into my database, but I  also want to acces these variables using a c# or delphi application. I wish to do this with JSON webservices. I wanted to know if this is possible, and if so, where to start. I'm quite new to JSON, so if anyone has any good article I could read please post it !

To be clear, I want something like this :

User fills in data -> PHP get data using `$_POST` -> PHP puts variable into database -> Creat a JSON webservice with the variable -> able to see the variable in a c# / delphi application

Wether to create the application in c# or delphi is still a decision I can't make.

I would like to hear your suggestions and/or information about this!

Comment: Start with JSON tutorials and you will have the first information.If you have specific questions afterwards, feel free to ask them.

Comment: http://www.secretgeek.net/json_3mins.asp  and http://Json.org